# Which numbers in an unordered list can be represented as a sum of 3 other numbers in the list?

Tags: algorithm

I encountered the following interview question online, and came up with O(N^2) solution.
I want to know if there is a better way to solve this problem?

Problem: Which numbers in an unordered list can be represented as a sum of 3 other numbers in the list?

My O(N^2) solution:

1. Create a hashmap that stores sum of all 2 element pairs.
   e.g. hashmap.insert(a[i] + a[j]),  0 <= i,j <= N-1
2. Once hashmap is built in step 1 (takes O(N^2) time,
   I will pick a pair from nC2 pairs and see if this pair contains
   the third element and the sum.
   i.e. For all pairs of two elements(a[p], a[q]) where 0 <= p,q <= N-1
   Find if hashmap contains (a[q] - a[p])

Comment: Palantir interview? :)

Answer (score 4):

Cannot do better than `O(N^2)` because if you then you would have solved one of the most difficult problems in computer science that is to solve 3-sum problem in less than O(N^2). It is still an open question whether 3-sum can be solved less than O(N^2).

[3-Sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3SUM)